# How to write Query Method on a subclass object using spring data jpa?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I want to fetch data from subclass via Query Method in spring data jpa. not want to use jpql or criteria api. I want to get all Connections with specified accountType and user. I know jpql as well as criteria api will do the job but i want to achieve this with JPA Query Method. Below is my code of entities and repos.

This is main entity class

```
@Entity
public class Connection {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
    @GenericGenerator(
            name = "UUID",
            strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator"
    )
    @Column(name = "Connection_Id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "User_Id", nullable = false)
    private String userId;

    @Column(name = "Name", nullable = false, length = 64)
    private String name;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "Connection_Type_Id")
    private ConnectionType connectionType;
    
    // default constructor
    
    // getter and setter
    
    }
```

this is abstract and concrete entity classes

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class ConnectionType {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
    @GenericGenerator(
            name = "UUID",
            strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator"
    )
    @Column(name = "Id", nullable = false)
    private String id;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "connectionType")
    private Connection connection;
    
    // default constructor
    
    // getter setter
}

@Entity
public class EmailAccount extends ConnectionType {
    
    @Column(name = "Username", nullable = false)
    private String username;
    
    @Column(name = "Password", nullable = false)
    private String password;
    
    
    @Column(name = "Account_Type", nullable = false)
    @Enumerated(value = EnumType.STRING)
    private AccountType accountType;
    
    @Column(name = "FullName")
    private String fullName;
    
    // default constructor
    
    // getter setter
    
}

@Entity
public class OtehrAccount extends ConnectionType {

    @Column(name = "Client_Id", nullable = false)
    private String clientId;
    
    @Column(name = "Client_Secret", nullable = false)
    private String secret;
    
    // default constructor
    
    // getter and setter
    
}
```

below is repository

```
public interface ConnectionRepository extends JpaRepository<Connection, String> {

    // Query Method that i want to write but is not valid.
    List<Connection> findByUserIdAndconnectionTypeAccountType(String userId, AccountType accountType);

}
```

findByUserIdAndconnectionTypeAccountType method in repo is incorrect so i just want to know weather or not is it possible to write method that will get me result based on subclass property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to clarify, "JPA Query Method" is actually "Spring Data JPA Query Methods", so this is not a Hibernate question. In JPQL/HQL this kind of subtype access usually works by using the `TREAT` operator, or in case of HQL, it also works implicitly. Since the Spring Data JPA documentation does not mention the treat operator, I would say it's not possible: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-creation

Answer (score 0):

`findByUserIdAndconnectionTypeAccountType` Means You Want To Fetch A Connection
By userId And The AccountType Where Is Field Of Entity ConnectionType .

- Class ConnectionType Have No Attribute With Name AccountType That You Want To Get A Connection By AccountType.
- AccountType Is An Attribute Of  A Subclass Of Class ConnectionType.
  So The connectionTypeAccountType Is Incorrect.
- **AccountType** Is Attribute Of Entity **EmailAccount** Wher Is Extending *ConnectioType*, You Canot Get A *Connection* With *AccountType*

Comment: I know that. I want to know whether it can be done by Query Method or not.